Running a django app on an apache server with Xampp
I am a junior dev and have landed my first role but have no one here to ask questions to.
I have been tasked with migrating our company app from the current server to a new server. I have been doing some research and looking through our code to orient myself with their system design. They are currently running their app directly from their server. I know nothing about server config.
From my research i found the mod_wsgi is used and have found the httpd.conf file and saw that it is point to the project folder on the C:/.
Can anyone walk me through the process of setting up a new server and what files i need to configure?
Currently they have it setup on an apache server which is controlled by xampp (all new to me).
I haven't toyed around with things too much because i changed branches the other day and their entire program companywide stopped working. So i dont want to start breaking things until i am sure i can recover it.
